# COUNT number of column values with INNER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, count

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I am making a Report. This is my SQL Fiddle:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ce465/5

So basically I have two tables, `responses` and `questions`. The structure is

```
responses
->id
->question_id
->response

questions
->id
->question
->costperlead
```

For the column `response` there can only be 3 values: `Yes`, `No`, `Possibly`.

And my report should have the columns

```
question_id
# of Yes Responses
# of No Responses
# of Possibly Responses
Revenue
```

where

- `# of Yes Responses` is the count of all `Yes` values in the `response` column,
- `# of No Responses` is the count of all `No` values in the `response` column,
- `# of Possibly Responses` is the count of all `Possibly` values in the `response` column,
- `Revenue` is `costperlead * ("# of Yes Responses" + "# of Possibly Responses")`.

I don't know how to construct the query. I'm new plus I came from MySQL, so some things will be different in PostgreSQL. In my SQL Fiddle sample most responses are `Yes` and Null – it's OK. Eventually, there will be `Possibly` and `No`.

So far I have only

```
SELECT a.question_id
FROM responses a INNER JOIN questions b ON a.question_id = b.id
WHERE a.created_at = '2015-07-17'
GROUP BY a.question_id ;
```

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: [X-posted to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31514856/939860) where I answered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answered at http://stackoverflow.com/q/31514856/939860

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you ?

```
SELECT a.id as question_id, a.costperlead, a.costperlead *(b.numYes+b.numPossible) as revenue,
b.numYes,b.numNo,b.numPossible
FROM questions a
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT a.question_id, 
count(case when a.response='Yes' then 1 end)AS numYes,
count(case when a.response='No' then 1 end) AS numNo,
count(case when a.response = 'Possibly' then 1 end) numPossible
FROM responses a 
GROUP BY a.question_id
)b ON b.question_id = a.id;
```

(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ce465/46)

Note: questions without responses will be also included in resultset. If it's not needed , replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.